# How to parent a bendy bone?

Tags: rigging

I am using Blender 3.3.0. I am creating a rig.
I have created a facial rig using bendy bones. I also have main body rig made with regular bones in the same armature as the facial bendy bone one.
When the rigs are not connected, bendy bone rig works fine: moving a controller moves a bone.
This is what i want to get
[image]

But when I parent bendy bone to the “head” bone, bendy bones get disconnected from their controllers (grey parallelepipeds)
(There is now a gap between a bendy bone and its controller)

[image]

Bendy bone Handles are set
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to connect controllers and bedy bones back? Or to parent bones so that bendy bones do not lose thir connection to their controllers?
I will be greatful for any help

my file
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Vsfy/ymeKQBn8D
one more link
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to parent correctly.
Only controllers should be paranted to the “head” bone. Bendy bones themselves should not be parented. Select the whole bendy bone you want to parent, deselect the bendys and then parent.
Like this:
[image]